# filter=total is returning 0?

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, filter

I'm running a very simple (and contrived) call of:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/115730?site=stackoverflow&filter=total
```

I'm expecting a response of:

```
{"total":1}
```

But am getting a response of:

```
{"total":0}
```

Changing the `filter` to something else (`default`, etc) results in the expected information, so it's not a quota thing.

Comment: This a pretty major bug, the total field returns 0 even with a custom filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this was a fun one.

Basically, a number of methods were figuring out that you weren't asking for any fields on an object type (like, say, users) and short-circuiting around database queries.  Unfortunately, there are *also* some methods that relying on the database queries to populate `total`.  This generally happened in the "query by id" methods.

So, I disentangled those methods so that short-circuiting won't happen when a method is expecting to figure out the `total` from the resulting data.

A fix has been deployed.